# Having problems compiling java file (ANT and XML related)

Tags: java, ant

Basically, when I execute the command `ant -f mybuild.xml clean junit-TestRunner`, I get lots of errors in my java file, it's giving errors on junit imports like:

```
    java:6: error: package org.junit does not exist
```

Here's a section of my xml file where it gives me errors on test-compile:

```
<path id="test.classpath">
   <pathelement location="${build.test.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="test-compile" depends="test-init">
      <javac srcdir="test" 
      destdir="build\test"
      includeAntRuntime="No"/>
</target>

<target name="junit-TestRunner" depends="test-compile">
  <java classname="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" 
        classpathref="C:\junit-4.10">
    <arg value="org.example.antbook.junit.SimpleTest"/>
  </java>

  <java classname="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" 
        classpathref="test.classpath">
    <arg value="org.eclipseguide.persistence.FilePersistenceServicesTest"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

I assume it cannot find the the directory where my junit-4.10.jar file is located. I've changed that in the 'classpathref', but still give me same errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding the full path to the JAR file, not only the directory where it is located.

Comment: You're not setting any classpath in the javac task in the test-compile target, so obviously, JUnit imports can't be resolved, since the junit jar is not in the classpath.

Comment: @JB - yeah I have tried putting my directory 'C:\junit-4.10' in the classpathref in Junit-TestRunner but still give me same errors.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of the classpathref attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)? It's supposed to be a reference to a path defined before. It's not supposed to contain a directory or jar path.

Comment: @JB - Just had a look at it. Does it mean it should be referencing java class file??

Comment: No. It should contain the ID of a path defined before in the build.xml file. And a classpath should contain paths to directories containing a root package, and paths to jar files.

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to understand it better. I have changed a few times on the ID of the path, but still give me errors. It compiles and finds the correct directory of the java file, but it can't detect the .jar file for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `junit.jar` into your `$ANT_HOME`. If you do that, you will cause problems when you install a new version of Ant, or if someone else checks out the file. Here's your problem:

```
<target name="junit-TestRunner" depends="test-compile">
   <java classname="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" 
       classpathref="C:\junit-4.10">
       <arg value="org.example.antbook.junit.SimpleTest"/>
   </java>
```

A `classpathref` is a ***reference*** to a classpath. It is defined separately, and it is not a jar or directory.

For example, before I call my `<java>` task, I first define my classpath reference:

```
<classpath id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement path="C:/junit-4.10"/>
</classpath>
```

This defines a ***reference*** to this classpath called `test.classpath`. You can now use it in your `<java>` task:

```
<target name="junit-TestRunner" depends="test-compile">
    <classpath id="test.classpath">
        <pathelement path="C:/junit-4.10"/>
    </classpath>

   <java classname="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" 
       classpathref="test.classpath">
       <arg value="org.example.antbook.junit.SimpleTest"/>
   </java>
```

Another thing you could do is simply include the `classpath`, so you don't have to define a reference to it in the first place:

```
<target name="junit-TestRunner" depends="test-compile">
   <java classname="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore">
       <arg value="org.example.antbook.junit.SimpleTest"/>
       <classpath>
           <pathelement path="C:/junit-4.10"/>
       </classpath>
   </java>
```

By the way, avoid the backslash. It can cause problems because it can sometimes be used as a *quoting character*. Instead, use a forward slash like I did in the above.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that makes your `build.xml` system dependent. If someone else checks out this code and tries to run tests it will most likely fail because he/she doesn't have `C:\junit-4.10` on his/her system.

Comment: @Cebence You're absolutely correct. It is best to put the junit.jar inside the project. Even better, use Ivy with Ant, and pull it out of a Maven repository. I didnt want to get into this at this point. However, even worse if you put `junit.jar` inside your `$ANT_LIB`. This makes the need for `junit.jar` absolutely invisible. You now have to figure out why this works on Bob's machine, but not Mark's machine. At least this way, you see that you need JUnit-4.10 as part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this:

```
classpathref="C:\junit-4.10"
```

should point to a jar file or a classes subdir under the above.

Comment: Hi Brian, Yes I have tried putting that on all the classpadref, but still give me same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the second "note" on [this page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)? I think the easiest way is #1, to put those JARs in `${ANT_HOME}/lib` folder. That way you don't have to specify any classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following target to your build.

```
<target name="bootstrap" description="Install build dependencies">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/junit.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar"/>
</target>
```

This will install the junit jar into one of ANT standard locations for 3rd party dependencies.